# Getting error in parfor but not in for-loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I am trying the matlab parallel processing and during this I tried to apply this thing to my code. Below is the code.

```
matlabpool open 2
pop = create_population(match_matrix,PopSize);
ftns = zeros(PopSize,1);
parfor i=1:PopSize
    ftns(i) = get_fitness(pop{i});
end
matlabpool close
```

The error I am getting is following

```
Error using parallel_function (line 589)

In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Error stack:
SWIFTga>(parfor body) at 127

Error in SWIFTga (line 126)
    parfor i=1:PopSize
```

I am getting no errors if I replace the parfor with for. Please suggest what may be going wrong....

Comment: That error suggests that the output from get_fitness is not a scalar value. It's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing the code in get_fitness and create_population.

Comment: The get_fitness gives scalar values, i checked manually setting breakpoint just before parfor. Even it does not give any error when i implement it in for loop. After for loop also all elements gets populated with scalar values.

Comment: In the parfor try doing:

  test = get_fitness(pop{i});
  disp(test);

to prove that you are getting what you expect.

Comment: I printed the input argument and then printed the output test. Input is ok but the output is empty []. Thats why it was showing error. But when I call the function get_fitness(arg) with same input argument, it does not show any error and returns a value which i expected. Does the parallel processing is affected by function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried so much and at last found the problem. Actually I was accessing global variables in the function called inside parfor body. From the matlab documentation found that we cant access global variables in parfor as there is synchronization issues. I has to change the code from global variables to argument passing. Thanks all for those who put some time into my question.